# Do I need a UK Transit Visa when my H-1B will expire the day after my travel?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, h1b-visas

I'm planning to travel to India departing USA on 23rd December 2015. My H-1B visa will expire on 25th December 2015. Can I travel on 24th December 2015 from London Heathrow to India Hyderabad?

My travel plan:

```
23rd Dec will start from USA   
24th Dec arrive LHR 11:30 and depart LHR 13:45   
25th Dec arrive in India 17:30
```

Comment: Your nationality will probably be an important bit of information to help answer the question.

Comment: Your visa expires on the 25th.  You will be transiting the UK on the 24th.  Your visa will therefore be valid during your transit.